# Is there a way to check whether a jekyll site is being served locally?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'd like to add the following line to my `head.html` solely when running `jekyll serve` locally:

```
  <script src="http://127.0.0.1:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></script>
```

I'm thinking of using some simple liquid check if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alternative solution *(for example, if you're hosting your Jekyll site on your own server and not on GitHub Pages)*:

You can set a value in the config file `_config.yml` like this:

```
environment: prod
```

Then, you can have another config file which overrides the same value, I'll call it `config_dev.yml`:

```
environment: dev
```

When you just call `jekyll build`, it will use the value `prod` from the real config file.

But when you build your site on your local machine for testing, you pass both config files in this order:

```
jekyll build --config _config.yml,_config_dev.yml
```

The value from the second config file will override the value from the first config file, so `environment` will be set to `dev`.

And then you can do the same as described in David's answer:

```
{% if site.environment == "dev" %}
  <script src="http://127.0.0.1:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></script>
{% endif %}
```

---

You can see an example in [the source code of my blog](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/blog/):

- [`_config.yml`](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/blog/src/d7de9936f5264eafe71964b552e947256ed22955/_config.yml?at=default)
- [`_config_dev.yml`](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/blog/src/d7de9936f5264eafe71964b552e947256ed22955/_config_dev.yml?at=default)
- [Windows batch file to run `jekyll build` in "dev" mode](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/blog/src/d7de9936f5264eafe71964b552e947256ed22955/build.bat?at=default)
- [Layout file](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/blog/src/d7de9936f5264eafe71964b552e947256ed22955/src/_layouts/default.html?at=default#cl-166), where I'm using the `environment` variable to:

  - disable Google Analytics in dev mode
  - change the URLs from where I'm loading JS and CSS files
    (dev mode: local server / prod mode: CDNs)

Comment: This is also an equally good solution, but as I've commented in the other answer I guess I'll leave the script line hanging around.

Answer (score 16):

When you do a `jekyll serve` locally the default `{{ jekyll.environment }}` variable is set to `"development"`.

You can then do a simple :

```
{% if jekyll.environment == "development" %}
  <script src="http://127.0.0.1:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></script>
{% endif %}
```

If you want to run jekyll on another server, with another `environment` value, you can set a `JEKYLL_ENV` **system environment variable** to whatever you want.

Setting this variable at runtime can be done like this :

```
JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll serve
```

Note : On Github Pages, `jekyll.environment` is set to `production`.

Comment: It seems it didn't work, the script tag ends up in page sources when running `jekyll serve` as well as running `jekyll build`.

Comment: Where are you doing this ? Locally, on a remote server, on github ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain how to set the environment variable.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I'm putting my site on GitHub, but I'm compilling it locally and pushing that since I'm using octopress 3. It seems I'll have to have that variable set in my machine, but since it's a web site to be edited by many hands/machines, I'm still unsure about the best approach. Maybe just letting the script tag hanging there would be the simplest.

Comment: In an Octopress deploy schema, Christian's answer is the one. Use multiple configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

> To preview your site with drafts, run `jekyll serve` or `jekyll build` with the `--drafts` switch. Each will be assigned the value modification time of the draft file for its date, and thus you will see currently edited drafts as the latest posts.

Did u try this?

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/