# Setting Jekyll environment for GitHub Pages

Tags: github, gulp, jekyll, github-pages, child-process

I am building a site with Jekyll that I am hosting on GitHub Pages. I would like to be able to set the JEKYLL_ENV to 'production' (`JEKYLL_ENV=production`) when I deploy to GitHub Pages so I can do something like this:

```
{% if jekyll.environment == "production" %}
{% include googleAnalytics.html %}
{% endif %}
```

and

```
{% if jekyll.environment == "production" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.min.css">
{% else %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">
{% endif %}
```

Now, I've read that GitHub Pages should automatically set the `JEKYLL_ENV` to `production`, but when I throw `{{ jekyll.enviornment }}` into my page, I get `development` both locally and on my hosted site. This may have do to with me building the site before I deploy using [this](https://github.com/shakyShane/jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync) and [this](https://github.com/shinnn/gulp-gh-pages).

My gulpfile.js

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var ghPages     = require('gulp-gh-pages');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var prefix      = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var minifyCss   = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename      = require('gulp-rename');
var cp          = require('child_process');

...

/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    return cp.spawn('jekyll', ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});

...

/**
 * Deploy to gh-pages
 */
gulp.task('deploy', ['jekyll-build'], function() {
    return gulp.src('./_site/**/*')
        .pipe(ghPages());
});
```

Essentially, when I run `gulp deploy`, I take the `_site` directory and push it to the `gh-pages` branch.

I don't know if this is causing the environment to be set to `development` or what, but what I am thinking of doing is instead of running the `jekyll-build` task in the `deploy` task is making and running a new `jekyll-build-prod` task that sets the `JEKYLL_ENV` to `production`.

This is the problem I'm running into. I'm not sure how to set the environment using `child_process` `spawns` (it was already written in [this](https://github.com/shakyShane/jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync) boilerplate). I've seen this command recommended: `$ JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll build`. I just seem to need to alter my `jekyll-build` task to incorporate that.

If there is a simpler way of doing this, I'd love to hear it.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I have tried including both a `_config.yml` where I set `environment: prod` and a `_config_dev.yml` where I set `environment: dev` and updating my gulp tasks to:

```
/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    return cp.spawn('jekyll', ['build', '--config', '_config.yml,_config_dev.yml'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});

/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site for production
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build-prod', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    return cp.spawn('jekyll', ['build', '--config', '_config.yml'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});
```

However, when I run the deploy task and check the hosted site, it still says the `environment` is `development`.

Even if I include `environment: prod` in both `_config.yml` and `_config_dev.yml`, it still says `development`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I finally figured out how to fix this issue. For whatever reason, the answer provided by @Christian Specht (using two different config files wasn't working). Instead I had to manually change the environments using the `child process spawns` in my gulp tasks. My updated `gulpfile.js`:

```
/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    return cp.spawn('jekyll', ['build'], { stdio: 'inherit' })
        .on('close', done);
});

/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site for production
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build-prod', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);

    var productionEnv = process.env;
    productionEnv.JEKYLL_ENV = 'production';

    return cp.spawn('jekyll', ['build'], { stdio: 'inherit' , env:productionEnv })
        .on('close', done);
});

/**
 * Deploy to gh-pages
 */
gulp.task('deploy', ['jekyll-build-prod'], function() {
    return gulp.src('./_site/**/*')
        .pipe(ghPages());
});
```

Answer (score 10):

I don't use GitHub Pages myself...but as I understand it, GitHub Pages sets the `JEKYLL_ENV` to `production` **when you push your source code to GitHub and let GitHub Pages build the site**.

You are doing something different: you are building your site locally and just push the finished HTML files (the `_site` folder), so GitHub Pages will never actually build your site.

This means that you need to take care of switching between `development` and `production` by yourself when you build your site locally.
The easiest way to do this is to use two separate config files, like I explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31296591/6884).

Comment: Correct, GiHub Pages is not actually building the site. I tried creating a `_config.yml` and `_config_dev.yml` and updating my gulp tasks (see my EDIT), but it seems the `_config.yml` is not being read.

Comment: I don't know Gulp, so I can't tell whether your Gulp tasks are correct. Did you try to directly execute the Jekyll commands via the command line without Gulp? Does that produce the desired results?

Comment: Yeah, it's strange. In my `index.html` I put `{{ jekyll.environment }}` and I've tried `jekyll build`, `jekyll build --config _config.yml`, and `jekyll serve` and they all result in `developement` even if I set both `_config.yml` and `_config_dev.yml` to `production`.

Comment: I just tried `JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll build` and that works, however. I don't know why the config files aren't working though.

Comment: To use two config files, you'd need to run `jekyll serve` similar to the following.  note the comma:

`bundle exec jekyll serve --config _config.yml,_config_dev.yml`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to host a site on GitHub pages using Jekyll, the best method is to use one repo, and have `gh-pages` branch in it.

The `gh-pages` branch is served as production and you can use your master or any other branch for local usage.

Since the branches are gonna be different you can make changes to files, add more files or any other changes you want to and the production will work accordingly.

Sample reference: https://github.com/VikramTiwari/blog

Comment: You're right, this does work. I did, however, like how `gulp-gh-pages` only pushed the `_site` folder contents to the `gh-pages` branch though. It made it a lot cleaner. If I can't figure out how to do it this other way, I'll have to end up doing this.