# Conditionally include JS script in html

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages

I am making a simple website hosted on Github Pages and use CDN to include several script files:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
```

During development on a local machine it is sometimes useful to include full versions of scripts to simplify debug, but on target server I'd prefer to use minified scripts, i.e. include `angular.min.js` instead of `angular.js`. Is there a way to have "conditional include" in html, or do Github Pages have some mechanism to substitute parts of last submitted files?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4451)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#specifying-a-jekyll-environment-at-build-time) says you can use the Jekyll environment to conditionally include code when building the site. For your case:

```
...
{% if jekyll.environment == "production" %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
{% else %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
{% endif %}
...
```

---

[Another option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274563/is-there-a-way-to-check-whether-a-jekyll-site-is-being-served-locally/31296591#31296591) suggests using another config file specifically for development.

`_config.yml` sets `environment: prod`.

`_config_dev.yml` sets `environment: dev`.

Running `jekyll build --config _config.yml,_config_dev.yml` in development, the second config file [overrides](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#build-command-options) the first and sets the environment to `dev`. GitHub Pages runs `jekyll build` - which only uses `_config.yml` - and would have environment set to `prod`. You could use a similar syntax to the above to conditionally include the file.

```
...
{% if site.environment == "prod" %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
{% else %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
{% endif %}
...
```