# Environments in Jekyll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

I'm a bit lost when dealing with environments using the Jekyll framework. I have a site that I wish to have a conditional to use google analytics in production.

Currently I have:

```
{% if jekyll.environment == 'production' %}
 {% include analytics.html %}
{% endif %}
```

Which displays nothing locally and on my server.

I have run the `JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll build` command locally as well.

Currently my config file just has general SEO tags.

Do I need to add the environments in the config file or setup two seperate config files?

Answer (score 0):

That snippet and command look good to me. One thing you could try is to include some dummy printout that renders in `development` environment.

```
{% if jekyll.environment == 'development' %}
    <p>This was built in a development environment</p>
{% elsif jekyll.environment == 'production' %}
    {% include analytics.html %}
{% endif %}
```

Try `jekyll build` and `JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll build` to make sure you're able to successfully build in different environments.

In terms of adding the environment to the config file or having multiple configs, you can also go that route. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101544/conditionally-include-js-script-in-html/50861667#50861667) should help with that route. But, try the first suggestion just to make sure nothing is wrong with your build process.

Comment: Thanks DC. Tried that method, but still no luck.

Comment: Do I need to setup something on my server to state that it's production?

Comment: In GitHub Pages, the server automatically sets `JEKYLL_ENV=production` and runs `jekyll build`. Since you mentioned having your own server, setting the environment to `production` can be done by setting the command `JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll build` to be run whenever the server receives new data.

If that first suggestion didn't work, then there might be something wrong with your build. You can try the second suggestion of multiple configs, but not being able to build off of `JEKYLL_ENV` is concerning.

Comment: Thanks DC. I'm not using Github pages for this. Maybe that where my problem is.